# Assembly LoadFrom identical Assembly not working

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I load assemblies at *runtime* from different folders. I then instantiate all types which contain a specific interface `typeof(I).IsAssignableFrom(xy)`

However, if the assembly containing the interface gets loaded by mistake (because someone placed it in one of the folders), no types will get loaded. I assume because of the mismatch with the interface type. I don't really understand why, since the **.dlls** are identical.

Also, is there a good way to fix this problem (I can´t get the strong name without `Assembly.LoadFrom`)

Additional Information:
as an example:
program.exe has a dll dependency interfacedefinition.dll

in a Subfolder of this program is a dll called "loading.dll".

if the interfacedefinition.dll exists in both, the main folder containing program.exe AND the Subfolder containing the loading.dll i get the described problem

Comment: You would have to use Load() instead of LoadFrom() or put the interface assembly in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

You should then prevent reloading the containing assembly by keeping a `List<string>` for example to hold a list of assembly names that should not be loaded. Check if the assembly you are about to load is contained in that `List`.

Comment: the interface is from the loaded assembly, but this assembly gets reloaded if it is also contained in the Directory where i load the other assemblies

Comment: I did not want to bother with conditional answers. Edited the response after @Markus replied.